# Count pages from word file that is a byte[]

Tags: c#, ms-word

Is there a way to count the pages of a word file that is currently a byte[]. 
In the Code you can see what i have so far. The formLanguage is an Entity from the Db and FormFile is a byte[] , here i am sure that it is a word.

```
 FileStream file = File.Create("EditedFile");
                        file.Write(formLanguage.FormFile, 0, formLanguage.FormFile.Length);
                        try
                        { 
                            var application = new Application();
                            var document = application.Documents.Open(file);

                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(e);

                        }
```

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: Word is an out-of-process app, it is incapable of reaching into your process and read a memory stream or byte[].  You need a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try as:

```
byte[] bytesDoc = byteFromDatabase();
var tempFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), formLanguage.FileName);
//Write to a temp file
File.WriteAllBytes(tempFile , bytesDoc );

var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Document doc = app.Documents.Open(tempFile);

var pageCount = doc.ComputeStatistics(
                   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdStatistic.wdStatisticPages);

doc.Close();
app.Quit();
```

Comment: Thank you this kind of worked i just put "Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), formLanguage.FileName)" insted of an absolute path

Comment: @BenjaminStucki  Happy to help. That's make change to use `GetTempPath()`.